# loopback angular sdk create is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loopback

I have problem with angular loopback sdk. I configured the project, created lb-services.js but when i try to call my API from my controllers the browser's console say

```
"{method name} is not a function".
```

here is my code:

**index.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">     </script>
        <![endif]-->
        <base href='/'/>
        <script src="vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/home.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/signup.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services/lb-services.js"></script>
    </head>
        <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
           <div ui-view></div>
        </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
   angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'lbServices'])
//Here are defined routes and controllers
```

**signup.js**

```
    angular.module('app')
  .controller('SignUpCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'Student',function($scope, Student){
$scope.registration = function(){
         birth = new Date($scope.formInfo.year, $scope.months.indexOf($scope.formInfo.month), $scope.formInfo.day);
         delete $scope.formInfo.year;
         delete $scope.formInfo.month;
         delete $scope.formInfo.day;
         $scope.formInfo.birthday = birth;
         Student.create($scope.formInfo)
            .$promise
            .then(function(student){
               console.log(student);
            });
      };
    }]);
```

where formInfo is a ng-Model of my form.
In this controller is Student.create that is not a function. Where is my error? Thank you for help

**EDIT**
Student is generated by sdk command lb-ng that generate lb-services.js

```
    // CommonJS package manager support
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof exports !== 'undefined' && module.exports === exports) {
  // Export the *name* of this Angular module
  // Sample usage:
  //
  //   import lbServices from './lb-services';
  //   angular.module('app', [lbServices]);
  //
  module.exports = "lbServices";
}

(function(window, angular, undefined) {'use strict';

var urlBase = "/api";
var authHeader = 'authorization';

function getHost(url) {
  var m = url.match(/^(?:https?:)?\/\/([^\/]+)/);
  return m ? m[1] : null;
}

var urlBaseHost = getHost(urlBase) || location.host;

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name lbServices
 * @module
 * @description
 *
 * The `lbServices` module provides services for interacting with
 * the models exposed by the LoopBack server via the REST API.
 *
 */
var module = angular.module("lbServices", ['ngResource']);
module.factory(
  "Student",
  ['LoopBackResource', 'LoopBackAuth', '$injector', function(Resource, LoopBackAuth, $injector) {
    var R = Resource(
      urlBase + "/students/:id",
      { 'id': '@id' },
      {

    "create": {
          url: urlBase + "/students",
          method: "POST"
        },

        /**
         * @ngdoc method
         * @name lbServices.Student#createMany
         * @methodOf lbServices.Student
         *
         * @description
         *
         * Create a new instance of the model and persist it into the data source.
         *
         * @param {Object=} parameters Request parameters.
         *
         *   This method does not accept any parameters.
         *   Supply an empty object or omit this argument altogether.
         *
         * @param {Object} postData Request data.
         *
         * This method expects a subset of model properties as request parameters.
         *
         * @param {function(Array.<Object>,Object)=} successCb
         *   Success callback with two arguments: `value`, `responseHeaders`.
         *
         * @param {function(Object)=} errorCb Error callback with one argument:
         *   `httpResponse`.
         *
         * @returns {Array.<Object>} An empty reference that will be
         *   populated with the actual data once the response is returned
         *   from the server.
         *
         * <em>
         * (The remote method definition does not provide any description.
         * This usually means the response is a `Student` object.)
         * </em>
         */
        "createMany": {
          isArray: true,
          url: urlBase + "/students",
          method: "POST"
        },

        /**
         * @ngdoc method
         * @name lbServices.Student#upsert
         * @methodOf lbServices.Student
         *
         * @description
         *
         * Update an existing model instance or insert a new one into the data source.
         *
         * @param {Object=} parameters Request parameters.
         *
         *   This method does not accept any parameters.
         *   Supply an empty object or omit this argument altogether.
         *
         * @param {Object} postData Request data.
         *
         * This method expects a subset of model properties as request parameters.
         *
         * @param {function(Object,Object)=} successCb
         *   Success callback with two arguments: `value`, `responseHeaders`.
         *
         * @param {function(Object)=} errorCb Error callback with one argument:
         *   `httpResponse`.
         *
         * @returns {Object} An empty reference that will be
         *   populated with the actual data once the response is returned
         *   from the server.
         *
         * <em>
         * (The remote method definition does not provide any description.
         * This usually means the response is a `Student` object.)
         * </em>
         */
        "upsert": {
          url: urlBase + "/students",
          method: "PUT"
        },

        /**
         * @ngdoc method
         * @name lbServices.Student#exists
         * @methodOf lbServices.Student
         *
         * @description
         *
         * Check whether a model instance exists in the data source.
         *
         * @param {Object=} parameters Request parameters.
         *
         *  - `id` – `{*}` - Model id
         *
         * @param {function(Object,Object)=} successCb
         *   Success callback with two arguments: `value`, `responseHeaders`.
         *
         * @param {function(Object)=} errorCb Error callback with one argument:
         *   `httpResponse`.
         *
         * @returns {Object} An empty reference that will be
         *   populated with the actual data once the response is returned
         *   from the server.
         *
         * Data properties:
         *
         *  - `exists` – `{boolean=}` - 
         */
        "exists": {
          url: urlBase + "/students/:id/exists",
          method: "GET"
        },

        /**
         * @ngdoc method
         * @name lbServices.Student#findById
         * @methodOf lbServices.Student
         *
         * @description
         *
         * Find a model instance by id from the data source.
         *
         * @param {Object=} parameters Request parameters.
         *
         *  - `id` – `{*}` - Model id
         *
         *  - `filter` – `{object=}` - Filter defining fields and include
         *
         * @param {function(Object,Object)=} successCb
         *   Success callback with two arguments: `value`, `responseHeaders`.
         *
         * @param {function(Object)=} errorCb Error callback with one argument:
         *   `httpResponse`.
         *
         * @returns {Object} An empty reference that will be
         *   populated with the actual data once the response is returned
         *   from the server.
         *
         * <em>
         * (The remote method definition does not provide any description.
         * This usually means the response is a `Student` object.)
         * </em>
         */
        "findById": {
          url: urlBase + "/students/:id",
          method: "GET"
        },

        /**
         * @ngdoc method
         * @name lbServices.Student#find
         * @methodOf lbServices.Student
         *
         * @description
         *
         * Find all instances of the model matched by filter from the data source.
         *
         * @param {Object=} parameters Request parameters.
         *
         *  - `filter` – `{object=}` - Filter defining fields, where, include, order, offset, and limit
         *
         * @param {function(Array.<Object>,Object)=} successCb
         *   Success callback with two arguments: `value`, `responseHeaders`.
         *
         * @param {function(Object)=} errorCb Error callback with one argument:
         *   `httpResponse`.
         *
         * @returns {Array.<Object>} An empty reference that will be
         *   populated with the actual data once the response is returned
         *   from the server.
         *
         * <em>
         * (The remote method definition does not provide any description.
         * This usually means the response is a `Student` object.)
         * </em>
         */
        "find": {
          isArray: true,
          url: urlBase + "/students",
          method: "GET"
        },

        /**
         * @ngdoc method
         * @name lbServices.Student#findOne
         * @methodOf lbServices.Student
         *
         * @description
         *
         * Find first instance of the model matched by filter from the data source.
         *
         * @param {Object=} parameters Request parameters.
         *
         *  - `filter` – `{object=}` - Filter defining fields, where, include, order, offset, and limit
         *
         * @param {function(Object,Object)=} successCb
         *   Success callback with two arguments: `value`, `responseHeaders`.
         *
         * @param {function(Object)=} errorCb Error callback with one argument:
         *   `httpResponse`.
         *
         * @returns {Object} An empty reference that will be
         *   populated with the actual data once the response is returned
         *   from the server.
         *
         * <em>
         * (The remote method definition does not provide any description.
         * This usually means the response is a `Student` object.)
         * </em>
         */
        "findOne": {
          url: urlBase + "/students/findOne",
          method: "GET"
        },

        /**
         * @ngdoc method
         * @name lbServices.Student#updateAll
         * @methodOf lbServices.Student
         *
         * @description
         *
         * Update instances of the model matched by where from the data source.
         *
         * @param {Object=} parameters Request parameters.
         *
         *  - `where` – `{object=}` - Criteria to match model instances
         *
         * @param {Object} postData Request data.
         *
         * This method expects a subset of model properties as request parameters.
         *
         * @param {function(Object,Object)=} successCb
         *   Success callback with two arguments: `value`, `responseHeaders`.
         *
         * @param {function(Object)=} errorCb Error callback with one argument:
         *   `httpResponse`.
         *
         * @returns {Object} An empty reference that will be
         *   populated with the actual data once the response is returned
         *   from the server.
         *
         * The number of instances updated
         */
        "updateAll": {
          url: urlBase + "/students/update",
          method: "POST"
        },

        /**
         * @ngdoc method
         * @name lbServices.Student#deleteById
         * @methodOf lbServices.Student
         *
         * @description
         *
         * Delete a model instance by id from the data source.
         *
         * @param {Object=} parameters Request parameters.
         *
         *  - `id` – `{*}` - Model id
         *
         * @param {function(Object,Object)=} successCb
         *   Success callback with two arguments: `value`, `responseHeaders`.
         *
         * @param {function(Object)=} errorCb Error callback with one argument:
         *   `httpResponse`.
         *
         * @returns {Object} An empty reference that will be
         *   populated with the actual data once the response is returned
         *   from the server.
         *
         * <em>
         * (The remote method definition does not provide any description.
         * This usually means the response is a `Student` object.)
         * </em>
         */
        "deleteById": {
          url: urlBase + "/students/:id",
          method: "DELETE"
        }
```

)

This is a piece of lb-services.js.

Comment: You need to supply your Student code for people to be able to help.

Comment: I think you're missing one of your injected services. Shouldn't `.controller('SignUpCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'Student',function($scope, Student)` be this: `.controller('SignUpCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'Student',function($scope, $state, Student)` ?

Comment: No. He gave me the same error :(

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why it isn't working because of the way you're bootstrapping your files in `index.html`.

Instead it should be like this.

```
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">     </script>
        <![endif]-->
        <base href='/'/>
        <script src="vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services/lb-services.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/home.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/signup.js"></script>
    </head>
        <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
           <div ui-view></div>
        </body>
</html>
```